# Grails 2.4, Spring Security Core and Spring Security Ldap plugins incompatibility issues

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-plugin, spring-security-ldap

Grails 2.4 depends on Spring 4, while Spring Security Ldap plugin is behind the race and depends on `org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core:1.3.2.RELEASE` which depends on Spring 3.

So, How can I use it?

Comment: (1) Wait (2) contribute to the project so that a new version is released (3) download the code that's targeted against spring 3 and do the necessary updates for spring 4 locally and deploy it to your local nexus.

Comment: I'd like to go the last two routes but I'm not a fluent java/groovy/grails developer, I've just started using it as a Rails equivalent on JVM.

Comment: Then you should probably use an older grails version if LDAP support is critical to you.

Comment: Incidentally I found out that there is not a clear dependencies between these package, http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-with-maven